# jQuery page on/live/bind pageinit, pageshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-applications, jquery-mobile

I'm working on application with jQuery mobile, I'm trying to put all the pages in userpanel into one big file and run it by one big .js file. What I don't know is if I can write my .js file in this way:

to initialize when userpanel is loaded

```
$(document).on('pageinit', function(){

});
```

and than when certain page will be called by id if I can put this:

```
$("#userpanel").on('pageshow', function(){

});
```

inside the first one like this for each and every page:

```
$(document).on('pageinit', function(){

    $("#userpanel").on('pageshow', function(){

    });

    $("#*********").on('pageshow', function(){

    });

    $("#*********").on('pageshow', function(){

    });

});
```

And so on, is this how it works or do I misunderstand basic concept of jQuery/JS? If yes what is a good way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all do not use **`page events`** as a children of other page events, there were not meant to work like that. In this case, all those **`pageshow`** events will trigger normally without their parent **`pageinit`**.

**[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/jg8Q2/)** a working **`jsFiddle`** example.

To find out more about **`jQuery Mobile`** page events take a look at this **[ARTICLE](http://www.gajotres.net/document-onpageinit-vs-document-ready/)**, to be more transparent it is my personal blog. Or it can be found **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14469041/1848600)**.

So correct way to declare page events would be like this:

```
$("#userpanel").on('pagebeforeshow', function(){

});

$("#userpanel").on('pageshow', function(){

});

$("#userpanel").on('pagebeforeshow', function(){

});

$("#userpanel").on('pageshow', function(){

});

$("#userpanel").on('pagebeforeshow', function(){

});

$("#userpanel").on('pageshow', function(){

});
```

Comment: Is there way to add script which would run only at the actual load of the .html file, but not when I'm switching between pages inside the file?

Comment: Logic is the same, just give them an id, only different thing is they must be loaded/initialized in a first HTML file.